# why getchar() function work different in a loop?

Tags: c, while-loop, getchar, putchar

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c;

    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
}
```

why when i input text such as for example "omar"put char print "omar" back .Isn't it supposed to print 'o' repeatedly since getchar will take first character only.I know that I am wrong about something probably because i don't know how exactly getchar or putchar works ,so can somebody please explain how they works.Another question why getchar and putchar work normally without a while loop but inside while loop behavior is something different.

Comment: `c` must be of type `int`.

Comment: It takes the first char, and the 'o' is removed. So next time, 'm' is the first char. And so on.

Comment: `getchar` and `putchar` work just the same regardless of the loop, so it is unclear why you would think that they work differently. Perhaps you are confused about what the loop does: it calls both `getchar` and `putchar` repeatedly, so the first calls read and print `o` in your `omar` example, the second calls print `m`, etc. (Meanwhile change `char c` to `int c` and search for a FAQ to explain why.)

Comment: when you type `o` `getchar` will receive the `o` it will be checked against `EOF` and `putchar` will print the `o` then the loop will return to `getchar`. This will then happen for `m` and `a` and `r`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why getchar() function work different in a loop?

I take you to be asking why `getchar()` works *differently than you expect*, as opposed to *differently than in other contexts*.  If you in fact meant the latter then the answer would be "it doesn't."

But of course reading a character from a stream, whether via `getchar()` or some other I/O function, removes it from the stream.  `getchar()` would not be very useful if it did not do that.  Therefore, if you call it repeatedly, you read (and remove) each character in turn until and unless all available characters are consumed.  You can test this by replacing the loop in your program with several `getchar()` calls in row.

And, of course, your loop *does* call it repeatedly.  The loop-control expression, `(c=getchar()) != EOF`, is evaluated before each iteration of the loop, and that involves calling `getchar()` (as opposed to using a value previously returned by that function).

---

On a completely separate note, do be aware that `getchar()` returns a result of type `int`, exactly so that it can return at least one value, `EOF`, that is outside the range of type `unsigned char`.  If you convert the result to type `char` then either there is one real input value that you will mistake for EOF, or you will never detect EOF, depending on whether `char` is signed or unsigned.  To reliably and portably detect the end of the file, you must handle that return value *as* an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: Nice answer, but add something about that c has to be an int for eof check to work

Comment: That's an issue with the OP's code, @Broman, but not germane to the actual question posed.  Comments on the question itself (and yours here) already address it.  Nevertheless, as a favor to you, I have added some comments about it.